# Decode ANSI output from command-line scripts automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, gulp

I'm running a command-line script as part of a Gulp task:

```
function runSQLScript(script) {
    child_process.execFile('sqlcmd', [
        '-S', process.env.DB_SERVER,
        '-U', process.env.DB_USER,
        '-P', process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        '-d', process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        '-f', 'i:65001',
        '-i', script
    ], {
        cwd: '../sql/sqlcmd'
        //, encoding: "???"
    }, function(error, stdout, stderr){
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log("" + stdout);
            console.error("" + error);
        }
        if (stderr.length>0) {
            console.error('' + stderr);
        }
    });
}
gulp.task('sql', function(){
    runSQLScript('install-app.sql');
});
```

When I run the script from a regular command-prompt the executable detects the current codepage and emits output in the appropriate encoding.

I don't know how to proceed in my Gulp task, though, since Node defaults to UTF-8 and [doesn't seem to support Windows encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) at all.

Is there a builtin way to get my script output properly decoded from default ANSI code page (850 in my PC, if that matters) or I need to install a conversion package and do it myself?

Comment: Windows encoding is generally `latin1` for most of Europe, North and South Americas and most of Southeast Asia

Comment: @slebetman Not really. In Western Europe (I can't speak for other regions) the default value for command-prompt is CP850 (the old MS-DOS codepage) and it's CP1252 (the old Windows codepage) in other contexts. They are both different from Latin-1.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do it.

For the records, a possible *manual* method would be:

```
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
console.log(iconv.decode(stdout, "CP850"));
console.error(iconv.decode(stderr, "CP850"));
```